# Matching prefix and multiple optional suffixes with no delimiter

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to regex match strings that have a prefix and two optional suffixes that can come in any order, where the prefix and each suffix is grouped separately e.g.

```
input       => groups
!attackH5E4 => (attack, H5, E4)
!attackE4H5 => (attack, H5, E4)
!HHHHHHH5   => (HHHHHH, H5, null)
!HHHHHHH5E4 => (HHHHHH, H5, E4)
!HHHHHHH5E4 => (HHHHHH, H5, E4)
!HHHHHHH5E4 => (HHHHHH, H5, E4)
```

The regex pattern I'm currently using is

```
!([^\s]+)(?:(H\d+)|(E\d+)){0,2}
```

where group 1 is the prefix (e.g. `attack`), group 2 is the H-modifier (e.g. `H5`), and group 3 is the E-modifier (e.g. `E4`).

As is, groups 2 and 3 get swallowed up by group 1. Throwing the `?` onto `[^\s]+` makes it match only the first character. Throwing `$` into the suffix non-capturing group doesn't work at all, unless I take off `{0,2}`.

[Here's a RegExr fiddle for the pattern, with test inputs and expected groups.](http://regexr.com/3gbhj)

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: See [`^!(\S+?)(?:(H\d+)|(E\d+)){0,2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/F8L4kh/3). I think you need to parse these strings as standalone strings, right?

Comment: @kirkpatt "I'm trying to regex match strings that have a prefix and two optional suffixes that can come in any order, where the prefix and each suffix is grouped separately." Edited to clarify. Sorry, I thought that was clear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks so much! That looks perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^!(\S+?)(?:(H\d+)|(E\d+)){0,2}$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xyIlZi/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `!` - a `!` symbol
- `(\S+?)` - any 1+ non-whitespace symbols, as few as possible
- `(?:(H\d+)|(E\d+)){0,2}` - 0 to 2 sequences of:

  - `(H\d+)` - Group 2: an `H` and 1+ digits
  - `|`  - or
  - `(E\d+)` - Group 3: an `E` and then 1 or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Note that `[^\s]` is equal to `\S` and it makes sense to use `[^\s]` only when you need to restrict the `\S` pattern (say, match any non-whitespace but some specific chars).

Comment: A fun fact: this trick with quantifying a non-capturing group having several capturing groups inside to match them in any order won't work in JavaScript. But with PCRE, it is possible, since a non-participating group is not cleared upon the next iterations.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed breakdown! This is phenomenally helpful.